# How to fix 'checkbox' in form

Tags: javascript, html, forms, checkbox, calculation

Hi I am stuck and I need help.

As shown in the coding provided below, it works fine if I remove all the 'Vaccinate checkbox' properties. But I need to have the 'checkbox vaccinate' property in this case.

Please try to keep most of the code provided as much as possible

It's school for homework.
Thankyou in advance!

```js
    function calculateCost() {

      var radioButton;
      var checkbox;
      var pet;
      var colour;
      var vaccinate;
      var cost = 0;

      var selectedPet = ["Cat", "Dog", "Rabbit"];
      var selectedColour = ["Black", "Gold", "White"];
      var selectedVaccinate = ["Vaccinate"];
      
      var selectedPetCost;
      var selectedColourCost;
      var selectedVaccinateCost;

      for (var i = 1; i <= 3; i++) {
        radioButton = document.getElementById(selectedPet[i - 1]);
        if (radioButton.checked == true) {
          pet = selectedPet[i - 1];
          selectedPetCost = parseInt(radioButton.value);
          //alert(parseInt(radioButton.value));
        }
      }
      
      if (!pet) {
        alert('No pet selected!');
      }

      for (var i = 1; i <= 3; i++) {
        radioButton = document.getElementById(selectedColour[i - 1]);
        if (radioButton.checked == true) {
          colour = selectedColour[i - 1];
          selectedColourCost = parseInt(radioButton.value);
          //alert(parseInt(radioButton.value));
        }
      }
      
      if (!colour) {
        alert('No colour selected!');
      }
      
      for (var i = 1; i <= 1; i++) {
        checkbox = document.getElementById(selectedVaccinate[i - 1]);
        if (checkbox.checked == true) {
          pet = selectedVaccinate[i - 1];
          selectedVaccinateCost = parseInt(checkbox.value);
        }
      }
      
      if (pet && colour && vaccinate) {
        cost = selectedPetCost * selectedColourCost * selectedVaccinateCost;
        alert("You have selected a " + pet + " and the colour selected was " + colour + ", the total cost is $" + cost);
      }
      
      if (pet && colour) {
        cost = selectedPetCost * selectedColourCost;
        alert("You have selected a " + pet + " and the colour selected was " + colour + ", the total cost is $" + cost);
      }
      
    }
```

```html
<form>
  <p>Choose a type of pet:
    <br>
    <input type="radio" id="Cat" name="pet" value="200"><label for="cat">Cat</label>
    <br>
    <input type="radio" id="Dog" name="pet" value="200"><label for="dog">Dog</label>
    <br>
    <input type="radio" id="Rabbit" name="pet" value="20"><label for="rabbit">Rabbit</label>
    <br>
  </p>
  
  <p>Choose the colour of pet:
    <br>
    <input type="radio" id="Black" name="colour" value="80"><label for="black">Black</label>
    <br>
    <input type="radio" id="Gold" name="colour" value="100"><label for="gold">Gold</label>
    <br>
    <input type="radio" id="White" name="colour" value="90"><label for="white">White</label>
    <br>
  </p>
  
  <p><label for="vaccinate">Vaccinate
<input type="checkbox" id="vaccinate" name="vaccinate" value="5"></label><br></p>

  <p><input type="button" value="Submit" onClick="calculateCost();">
</form>
```

Comment: Is it or me or everyone i see very complicated way to achieve?

Comment: The check.box - Vaccinate is the problem @S.Serp

Comment: @JamesLi Please upvote the answer as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have done couple of mistakes in your function and I have fixed those issues. Please try below code

```
function calculateCost() {

  var radioButton;
  var checkbox;
  var pet;
  var colour;
  var vaccinate;
  var cost = 0;

  var selectedPet = ["Cat", "Dog", "Rabbit"];
  var selectedColour = ["Black", "Gold", "White"];
  var selectedVaccinate = ["vaccinate"];

  var selectedPetCost;
  var selectedColourCost;
  var selectedVaccinateCost;

  for (var i = 1; i <= 3; i++) {
    radioButton = document.getElementById(selectedPet[i - 1]);
    if (radioButton.checked == true) {
      pet = selectedPet[i - 1];
      selectedPetCost = parseInt(radioButton.value);
      //alert(parseInt(radioButton.value));
    }
  }
  if (!pet) {
    alert('No pet selected!');
    }

  for (var i = 1; i <= 3; i++) {
    radioButton = document.getElementById(selectedColour[i - 1]);
    if (radioButton.checked == true) {
      colour = selectedColour[i - 1];
      selectedColourCost = parseInt(radioButton.value);
      //alert(parseInt(radioButton.value));
    }
  }
  if (!colour) {
    alert('No colour selected!');
  }

     for (var i = 1; i <= 1; i++) {
    checkbox = document.getElementById(selectedVaccinate[i - 1]);
    if (checkbox.checked == true) {
      vaccinate = selectedVaccinate[i - 1];
      selectedVaccinateCost = parseInt(checkbox.value);
    }
  }
  if (pet && colour && vaccinate) {
    cost = selectedPetCost * selectedColourCost * selectedVaccinateCost;
    alert("You have selected a " + pet + " and the colour selected was " + colour + ", the total cost is $" + cost);
  }
  else if (pet && colour) {
    cost = selectedPetCost * selectedColourCost;
    alert("You have selected a " + pet + " and the colour selected was " + colour + ", the total cost is $" + cost);
  }
}
```

[Working example](https://jsfiddle.net/Suvethan/9so85ksy/)

As far as I understood,When you select only the pet and colour you should the cost for the pet and colour,whereas when select with vaccination you should get cost for pet and colour with vaccination. I hope this answer fix your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Here is your javascript code.

```js
        function calculateCost() {

      var radioButton;
      var checkbox;
      var pet;
      var colour;
      var vaccinate;
      var cost = 0;

      var selectedPet = ["Cat", "Dog", "Rabbit"];
      var selectedColour = ["Black", "Gold", "White"];
      var selectedVaccinate = ["vaccinate"];
      
      var selectedPetCost;
      var selectedColourCost;
      var selectedVaccinateCost;

      for (var i = 1; i <= 3; i++) {
        radioButton = document.getElementById(selectedPet[i - 1]);
        if (radioButton.checked == true) {
          pet = selectedPet[i - 1];
          selectedPetCost = parseInt(radioButton.value);
          // alert(parseInt(radioButton.value));
        }
      }
      

      for (var i = 1; i <= 3; i++) {
        radioButton = document.getElementById(selectedColour[i - 1]);
        if (radioButton.checked == true) {
          colour = selectedColour[i - 1];
          selectedColourCost = parseInt(radioButton.value);
          //alert(parseInt(radioButton.value));
        }
      }
      

      
      for (var i = 1; i <= 1; i++) {
        checkbox = document.getElementById(selectedVaccinate[i - 1]);
        if (checkbox.checked == true) {
          vaccinate = selectedVaccinate[i - 1];
          selectedVaccinateCost = parseInt(checkbox.value);
          //alert(selectedVaccinateCost);
        }
      }
      
      if (pet && colour && vaccinate) {
        cost = selectedPetCost * selectedColourCost * selectedVaccinateCost;
        alert("You have selected a " + pet + " and the colour selected was " + colour + ", the total cost is $" + cost);
      }else if (pet && colour) {
        cost = selectedPetCost * selectedColourCost;
        alert("You have selected a " + pet + " and the colour selected was " + colour + ", the total cost is $" + cost);
      }
      
    }
```

```html
  <form>
  <p>Choose a type of pet:
    <br>
    <input type="radio" id="Cat" name="pet" value="200"><label for="cat">Cat</label>
    <br>
    <input type="radio" id="Dog" name="pet" value="200"><label for="dog">Dog</label>
    <br>
    <input type="radio" id="Rabbit" name="pet" value="20"><label for="rabbit">Rabbit</label>
    <br>
  </p>
  
  <p>Choose the colour of pet:
    <br>
    <input type="radio" id="Black" name="colour" value="80"><label for="black">Black</label>
    <br>
    <input type="radio" id="Gold" name="colour" value="100"><label for="gold">Gold</label>
    <br>
    <input type="radio" id="White" name="colour" value="90"><label for="white">White</label>
    <br>
  </p>
  
  <p><label for="vaccinate">With vaccinations
<input type="checkbox" id="vaccinate" name="vaccinate" value="5"></label><br></p>

  <p><input type="button" value="Submit" onClick="calculateCost();">
</form>
```

You've made named the "vaccinate" variable as "pet" on vacinate section. So, this was the problem why it didn't calculate the actual cost. So, I renamed the "pet" variable as "vaccinate" and it works fine.

Answer (score -1):

ok i got do some jquery for what i understand of what you try to achieve

```js
$('.calculate').click(function(){
animal=$('input[name=animal]:checked').val();
color=$('input[name=color]:checked').val();
if(animal == null || color ==null){
color='nothing'
animal='Nothing'
}
$('.inside').text('You choose '+animal+' Also color '+color);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span>Choose animal you like</span><br>
<input type='radio' name='animal' value='dog'>dog<br>
<input type='radio' name='animal' value='cat'>cat<br>
<input type='radio' name='animal' value='donkey'>dnkey<br>
<span>Choose Color you like</span><br>
<input type='radio' name='color' value='Green'>Green<br>
<input type='radio' name='color' value='Blue'>greeb<br>
<input type='radio' name='color' value='red'>green<br>
<button class='calculate'>
Calculate
</button><br>
<div class='inside'>
Strange huh?
</div>
```

Comment: Nice try but I think you have missed what he actually wanted